# VBA Find/Replace & Text Color Change

Tags: excel, vba, replace, find

I've a spreadsheet with three columns. Column A has some sentences in it (written in black font color). Columns C has a list of terms to search for. And column D has a list of replace terms (written in red font color).

I'm trying to search the sentences in column A for the search terms in column C. And, if column A contains any of the search terms in column C, replace the text in column A with the replace terms in column D.

The find/replace feature works great. But I haven't been able to get the font color of the replaced portion of the string in column A to turn red.

Any thoughts?

Here's the code I've got so far.

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()

For i = 3 To 6

     Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A2:A35").Select

     Selection.Replace What:=Cells(i, 3).Value, Replacement:=Cells(i, 4).Value, _
     LookAt:=xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, MatchCase:=False

Next

Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(1, 1).Select

End Sub
```

Comment: Could you include an example of demo input/output? I think I understand what you're trying to do, but it's easier if I can see what you expect the results to be

Comment: I think what you want to do is set the `ReplaceFormat` and set it to `Font.Color = RGB(255,0,0)` or something along those lines.

Comment: This does seem to replace the formatting of the entire cell, however. Not just the text that was found originally.

Comment: if formatting varies within a cell, you will need to loop through all the characters to set the formatting to what you want.

Comment: Off the top of my head, you could find-replace and use something like `$!{replaced text}$!` and then follow up your replacement with a search for `$!{*}$!` and update the formatting for those sections before removing the `$!{}$!` portion of the string. Might just make it easier to know exactly what is being changed without having to check the text of every single cell. Of course, you COULD also just do the find->replace yourself using variant arrays or something - that's likely the fastest way.

Comment: Yes, that is what I'm after: some sort of Font.Color = RGB(255,0,0). Not sure how to incorporate it though.

Here's an example, if that's helpful.

Column A = "This is a test."

Column C (find column) = "test"

Column D (replace column) = "practice"

Result = "This is a practice test."

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()

For i = 3 To 6

     Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A2:A35").Select

     With Application.ReplaceFormat
       .Font.Color = vbRed
     End With

     Selection.Replace What:=Cells(i, 3).Value, Replacement:=Cells(i, 4).Value, _
     LookAt:=xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, MatchCase:=False, ReplaceFormat:=True

Next

Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(1, 1).Select

End Sub
```

[Microsoft Explanation:](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.application.replaceformat)

> Sets the replacement criteria to use in replacing cell formats. The replacement criteria is then used in a subsequent call to the Replace method of the Range object.

Comment: Thanks for getting back to me. We're getting close here. The above solution changes all the words in the cell to red. Is it possible to only change the replaced portion of the string to red while the rest of the text in the cell remains black?